# Set active Bootstrap nav dropdown when any item in the list is active in React-Router v4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router v4 and trying to write up a wrapper that allows the Bootstrap dropdown class to be active. The gist is that I need match multiple routes, and I'm unsure exactly how to do that in this wrapper.

Here is what I have:

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const DropDownLinkWrapper = ({links, label}) => {
  return (
    <Link to="/link1|/link2"> // <-- this is what I want to do
      {({isActive}) =>
        <li className={`dropdown ${isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}>
          <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
             aria-expanded="false">{label}<span className="caret"/></a>
          <ul className="dropdown-menu">
            {// output menu links here}
          </ul>
        </li>
      }
    </Link>
  );
};

DropDownLinkWrapper.propTypes = {
  links: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default DropDownLinkWrapper;
```

I would imagine that the first `<Link/>`'s `to` prop would need to match on two URLs. But of course, this doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: You won't be able to do this with `<Link>`. You will need to implement a component that can check multiple locations against the current pathname. I actually have a higher-order component in a component library that I've been working on that _should_ be useful here. I can link it if you would like to take a look.

Comment: Sure! That would be great!

Comment: I know that I said it in my above comment, but for full disclosure, this _is_ my own project. The source code is at https://github.com/pshrmn/rrc and specifically I am referring to the `whenActive` higher order component. You would need to pass is an `isActive` function (see the `isActive` test for an example). If nothing else, hopefully it will help push you in the right direction for building your own component to do something similar.

Comment: I forgot to note before that this is meant to be compatible with the upcoming beta. It is a little bit of a pain to use right now because you have to `git clone` and `npm link` the `v4` branch in order to use it right now. The beta will hopefully be released soon, at which time it will be more practical to test this out.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulS. I really appreciate it!